# What happeneds to temporary variables when a macro expands to nothing?

Tags: c++, macros

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
// calls appropriate functions for message logging
#define LOGMESSAGE( stdStr ) gLogger.LogMessage( stdStr, __FILE__, __LINE__ );
// calls appropriate function for success logging
#define LOGSUCCESS( stdStr ) gLogger.LogSuccess( stdStr, __FILE__, __LINE__ );
// calls appropriate function for error logging
#define LOGFAILURE( stdStr ) gLogger.LogFailure( stdStr, __FILE__, __LINE__ );
#endif

#ifdef NDEBUG
// does nothing in release mode
#define LOGMESSAGE( stdStr )
// does nothing in release mode
#define LOGSUCCESS( stdStr )
// Logs failures in release mode
#define LOGFAILURE( stdStr ) gLogger.LogFailure( stdStr, __FILE__, __LINE__ );
#endif
```

Say I call the macros like the following

```
if ( SomeFunc() )
    {
    LOGSUCCESS("Success calling SomeFun()");
    }
else
    {
    LOGFAILURE("Failure calling SomeFun()");
    }
```

In release mode LOGSUCCESS is blank so does that mean "Success calling SomeFunc()" string isn't compiled into the code and won't exist in the compiled code, or is that left over, but the macro doesn't do anything with it?

EDIT:
I mean does it effectively leave the code like this in release mode?

```
if ( SomeFunc() )
    {
    "Success calling SomeFun()";
    }
else
    {
    gLogger.LogFailure("Failure calling SomeFun()", __FILE__, __LINE__ );
    }
```

or

```
if ( SomeFunc() )
    {

    }
else
    {
    gLogger.LogFailure("Failure calling SomeFun()", __FILE__, __LINE__ );
    }
```

Comment: Run the preprocessor and see for yourself!

Comment: There's no difference between those two things. Something that has literally no effect is indistinguishable from nothing at all.

Comment: What do you mean run the preprocessor?

Comment: @EddieV223: Use -E flag for `gcc`. It will stop after preprocessing stage, which expands the macros and include.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz - "There's no difference between those two things" - could you further clarify this - which two things? What if the debug Str contained sensitive information. Including, but not using it would be a problem..

Comment: @EddieV223: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z9z0bx6%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: The macro should expand to nothing, but it won't eat the semicolon after, so neither of your examples is exact.

Comment: Cool I had no idea you could run the preprocessor and output to a file, that's awesome!  Thank you.  I feel like a blind man who can now see.

Comment: If it was included in the compiled code, then the macro would have included it in the compiled code. We were talking about two cases, one where the string "won't exist in the compiled code" and another where the macro "doesn't do anything with it". These are the same case -- the string can't exist in the compiled code unless the macro does something with it. (What, other than the macro, could put the string in the compiled code? The string only goes to the macro.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will be expanded to -

```
if ( SomeFunc() )
    {
; //Remember the semicolon here
    }
else
    {
    gLogger.LogFailure("Failure calling SomeFun()", __FILE__, __LINE__ );
    }
```

The macro resolution is a pre-compile time activity, which just replaces the definition into the code before compilation starts.

You have not associated any "meaning" to your debug dynamic information in the macro - so it is not used at all.

To put it in simple term, macro is just a "search and replace" kind of activity during pre-compilation. Now since the str is not defined in the macro, it is not "used". Since it is a kind of pre-compile time activity,the question of temporary variable does not arise.